# Reader root in ExtJS with nested JSON array

Tags: extjs, grid

I'm trying to fill the grid with part of data i'm taking from JSON. For example (shortnen version), JSON looks like this:

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "machine1",
      "devices": {
        "disk": [
          {
            "type": "file",
            "device": "disk",
          },
          {
            "type": "block",
            "device": "cdrom",
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      "name": "machine2",
      "devices": {
        "disk": [
          {
            "type": "file",
            "device": "disk",
          },
          {
            "type": "block",
            "device": "cdrom",
          }
        ],
    },
  ]
}
```

To get info about `machine1`'s disks i need to get to `data[0].devices.disk`, so i thought about changing `store.proxy.reader.root` property like `root = 'data[0].devices.disk'` or `root = 'data.0.devices.disk'` but both didn't work. 
I know the easiest way is to change the JSON response, but i'm interested if i am able to fill the grid without changing the JSON.

Comment: What data are you trying to extract, a list of what?

Comment: I'm trying to get grid, which rows are elements of array 'disk' and columns are 'type' and 'device'.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'data[0].devices.disk' worked for me.  Your example JSON was a little messed up though with some trailing commas.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWzBd/)

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['type', 'device']
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myData = '{"data":[{"name":"machine1","devices":{"disk":[{"type":"file","device":"disk"},{"type":"block","device":"cdrom"}]}},{"name":"machine2","devices":{"disk":[{"type":"file","device":"disk"},{"type":"block","device":"cdrom"}]}}]}';

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        data: Ext.decode(myData),
        proxy: {
            type:'memory',
            reader: {
                type:'json',
                root: 'data[0].devices.disk'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        stateful: true,
        collapsible: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        stateId: 'stateGrid',
        columns: [
            {
                text     : 'type',
                dataIndex: 'type'
            },
            {
                text     : 'device',
                dataIndex: 'device'
            }
        ],
        height: 350,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Array Grid',
        renderTo: 'grid',
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true,
            enableTextSelection: true
        }
    });
});
```