# Placing JSON response elements into a store- Ext JS

Tags: json, extjs

I'm wondering what the best way would be to load elements of a JSON response into a store.

**What I have:**

jQuery ajax request

```
var foodRequest = $.ajax({
    url: "MyServlet",
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(searchquery),
    error : function() {
        alert ('ERROR!! Please re-enter the search criteria and try again.');
                }
});
```

ajax response

```
{
 "Foods":[
  {
     "Food":{
        "name":"Spaghetti",
        "id":"001",
        "attributes":[
           {
              "attrname":"Price",
              "attrvalue":"18.99"
           },
           {
              "attrname":"Description",
              "attrvalue":"Spaghetti is delicious, don't argue with me"
           },
           etc...
```

**What I want:**

(each element has 4 attributes)

```
var grid = Ext.define('Myapp.view.Grid' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    id: 'mygrid',', 
    initComponent: function(columns) {

        this.columns = [
            {header: 'attrname',  dataIndex: 'attrvalue', flex: 2 },
            {header: 'attrname',  dataIndex: 'attrvalue', flex: 2 },
            {header: 'attrname',  dataIndex: 'attrvalue', flex: 2 },
            {header: 'attrname',  dataIndex: 'attrvalue', flex: 2 },
            etc...
```

How can I take the attributes from the json response and place them into a store my grid can use, as seen above?

Cheers!

Comment: Is your question asking how to parse the data? Or just how to call the function to load it?

Comment: Does the data need parsing? Sorry, I'm new at this. I just want to load all this data into a store and display each attribute to it's respective field. o_o

Comment: What do you mean "load all the data"? It's a table of stuff. What do you want to display in the grid? The data structure doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Edited the question, hopefully I'm making sense here.

Comment: Follow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522423/reader-root-in-extjs-with-nested-json-array

Answer (score 1):

The data you are returning looks like a tree. A normal grid works with fixed columns. In short:

- a grid uses a store
- the Store uses a number of fields or a Model.
- a grid has a number of predefined columns, each column references a store(model) field by means of a dataIndex.

Now when the store loads data (either through a proxy or by manually dumping records in it). it creates a record internally. The fields on the record that are available are the fields you defined on the store or the fields you defined on the model the store uses.

Long story short, the normal setup of a grid and store is with a fixed number of columns and fields. In your case it would probably be better to use a TreePanel and store. Look at the treepanel example for this.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/extjs-build/examples/tree/treegrid.html

Good luck

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but what I'm trying to do is exactly what you initially said - load my response data into a store. Perhaps I worded the question strangely.

Comment: Hi Clay,Then you have to make sure your return data is 'flat'. If you return an object with 3 fields: {success: true, total: NR_OF_RECORDS, records: [{ key: value, key2: value2}] it should work without problems. Your data is nested like a tree (Foods -> Food -> attributes). Of course there is always a way to make it read your data, but you would have to create a custom renderer. To be able to provide an example I would need to know how your store looks like

Comment: Thank you very much Rob, I've solved my issue with the help of another user on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056939/placing-json-string-into-a-store/22058112?noredirect=1#22058112