# Placing JSON string into a store

Tags: json, extjs

Simple question here. How could I place this JSON string into an Ext.data.Store?

```
   {
   "elements":[
      {
         "element":{
            "name":"value 1",
            "id":"element 1",
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "attrname":"id",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the ID"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"name",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the name"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"description",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the description"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"table_name",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the table"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

This is a simplified version of my question: [Placing JSON response elements into a store- Ext JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052367/placing-json-response-elements-into-a-store-ext-js?noredirect=1#comment33439776_22052367)

Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide more information? Where is this JSON coming from? A store will store Model instances; Is this store going to store multiple instances of "element"? Looks like each "attribute" will be an instance of a separate model. You can use associations for that.

Comment: My JSON is coming from a request from my server, which I turn into a string. Now I'm trying to take these individual attributes and place them into a store so I can then place into a grid. If you follow my link it will give you a bit more detail

Comment: Follow this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522423/reader-root-in-extjs-with-nested-json-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing JSON response elements into a store- Ext JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052367/placing-json-response-elements-into-a-store-ext-js)

Comment: Obviously it's a possible duplicate, I linked the damn thing for God's sake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSON is coming back from the server, the first thing you'll need to do is to deserialize it from a JSON-formatted string into an object that you can navigate. Assuming that it's valid JSON, you can simply do this by using Ext.decode().

This will give an object that has an array of objects at the "elements" key. Simply loop over the elements array and create a new model instance that can be inserted into your store.

Here's a link to a live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3u6

And here's the code from that example:

```
var data = YOUR_DATA_HERE,
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'description', 'table_name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }
})
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Test Data',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id'
    }, {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Description',
        dataIndex: 'description'
    }, {
        text: 'Table Name',
        dataIndex: 'table_name'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
var decoded = Ext.decode( data );
// loop over decoded data
for( var i=0; i<decoded.elements.length; i++ ) {
    var element = decoded.elements[ i ].element;
    // set implicit model
    var model = {};
    // loop over attributes
    for( var x=0; x<element.attributes.length; x++ ) {
        var attribute = element.attributes[ x ];
        model[ attribute.attrname ] = attribute.attrvalue;
    }
    // implicitly cast data as Model
    store.add( model );
}
```

Comment: How can I pull elements.element.name out of the model and place it into it's own column?

Comment: It should be as easy as model[ "somecolumnname" ] = elements.element.name

Comment: Thank you so much @existdissolve, this was a fantastic solution. Is this model mapping that is going on when you define model[ "soandso"] etc.?

Comment: Kind of. All that this script is really doing is creating a generic JS object with key/value pairs. Since the store has a "fields" definition, it will automatically do its best to cast the incoming JS object to a model that the store knows how to use. There is a full API for create user-defined Models, and using proper getter/setter methods to interact with the Model's properties. Ultimately, I would suggest that you go in that direction since the "fields" configuration doesn't lend itself to reusability, whereas the proper Model definition would.